# Ways to reduce the number of activity

Tags: android-activity

My friends, I wanted a solution to not open an activity for each page in the program because the number of activities is too large.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does the program do?

Comment: if you want to reduce the number of activities please use fragments and replace with another fragments.